# Itext7 generate Pdfa java

Tags: itext7, pdfa

***Cannot close document with already flushed PDF Catalog.***

You know what this error means. It happens when I use the command with Itext7

document.close() or PdfDocument.close

I've searched the internet and here but can't find any documentation .

```
    pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(this.path_documento + this.nome_documento);  
    PdfOutputIntent pdfOutputIntent = new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "https://www.color.org","sRGB2014", new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\UC9001309\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GestionePdf\\sRGB2014.icc") );

    pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(pdfWriter, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A,pdfOutputIntent);      
    document = new Document(pdfDocument);  
    PdfFont  font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER_BOLD); 
    
    
    pdfDocument.setTagged();
    pdfDocument.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("it-IT")); 
    pdfDocument.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
    
    PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo();
    info.setTitle("Pdf generato da GestPdf");
```

The code above is creating the pdfa then there are adding 2 pages and then calling the methods

document.close () or PdfDocument.colose

Comment: Please share enough code to allow reproducing the error. Also please show the stack trace of the error.

Comment: The code is made up of multiple classes it is not possible to post it.

Stack Trace : com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Cannot close document with already flushed PDF Catalog.

Comment: I have not seen that exception yet in practice. So i can only assume that there is some error in those *multiple classes* of yours. What you should do, therefore, is remove more and more of the stuff you do to the `Document` or `PdfDocument` before closing until the error does not occur anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But  you know what flushed PDF Catalog technically means .

Comment: The PDF catalog is the central object in a PDF; it points to other objects like the pages tree or the form definition. A PDF object in iText is called *flushed* if it has already been stored in the underlying `PdfWriter`, e.g. as a consequence of a `pdfDocument.getCatalog().getPdfObject().flush()` call.

Comment: Thanks, these two lines in response are the solution to my problem.